Why is there no power to the heating system in my flat?
I turned off the power in my flat (UK) to change a light fixture. When I turned it back on everything worked…except the switch for the heating. It’s a central boiler with an evinox satellite unit. The heating system also doesn’t seem to be labeled on the circuit breaker. I changed the fuse on the switch, but it didn’t change anything. 


Two questions: 1) Which breaker/switch did you turn off to remove the power? 2) What do you mean by your boiler being a central boiler with a satellite unit? Does the boiler serve multiple flats? If so, is the heating/hot water working for your neighbors you are sharing the boiler with?

@BartvanIngenSchenau 1) The big red one. 2) There is a boiler in the basement for the whole block. Each flat has one of these, apologies if my terminology is wrong. As far as I can tell everyone else still has hot water.

have you checked whether any of the wires in the switch are live?

@JoSSte Yes, if I take the cover off the heating system switch and stick the voltage pen in there it beeps.

I would probably contact an electrician, but try to isolate which of the sub-groups that unit is connected  to and see if anything else is also not working when you turn of that group only.

@JoSSte Seems I will have to. But weirdly I've tried everything else in the flat and everything is fine.

A voltage pen will show power in the switch.  Have you checked the fuse?  If the fuse is blown, there will not be power to the unit, only to that switch.

@crip659 Yes unfortunately I replaced the fuse straight away. It was one of those non-clear ceramic ones, but showed no signs of damage. No change after replacement.
